# Open ASPX form from Dojo

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dojo

I want to open my aspx form using Dojo? Is it possible? Please guide me. My code is as under

```
OpenMyForm: function() {
          dojo.xhrGet({
                      url: "WebForm2.aspx",
                      handleAs: 'json'
                     });
                   }
```

When I run this code, there is no error but no form opens either.

My aspx is

```
<body>
  <div id="frm">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="clist">

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"    onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

    </div>
    </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to something like this:

```
OpenMyForm: function() {
  alert("Will make a request now!");
  dojo.xhrGet({
      url: "WebForm2.aspx",
      handleAs: 'text',
      load: function(text) { alert("Success! " + text); },
      error: function(error) { alert("An error occurred! " + error); }
  });
  alert("Made the request, now waiting for the response!");
}
```

This should give you an idea of where things stop working.

The `load` function is the key. It is called when the request succeeds, so that is where you want to tell Javascript what to do with the "form" that the server produces. <s>If the above seems to work, you can try adding this:</s>

Assuming the above works (which is does, based on your comment), you can try to actually place the form on the page. Replace this line:

```
load: function(text) { alert("Success! " + text); },
```

with this:

```
load: function(text) { document.getElementById("some_div").innerHTML = text; },
```

Make sure you have a div on your page with id "some_div" (or change it accordingly). Instead of a success dialog, the script now puts the text (your aspx form, hopefully) on the page.

If you want to show the new form in a dialog, you can replace the load line with these lines instead:

```
load: function(text) {
    var dialog = dijit.byId("some_dialog");
    dialog.set("content", text);
    dialog.show();
},
```

Notice that it expects a dijit.Dialog to have been created earlier. For example, somewhere else in your script, you would have something like:

```
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.ready(function() {
    window.myDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
        id: "some_dialog",
        title: "My dialog!"
});
```

Make sure you've included the dijit.css, of course (see examples of dijit.Dialog here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/Dialog.html ).

Comment: Thanks. That works partially. The "Success" dialog is displayed but my actual form which has a button on it is not displayed. Instead I get a check box "Prevent his dialog to display additional dialogs". Any idea why?

Comment: @user2837961 Great! You get the "Prevent this.." message because of all the `alert`s I put in the code to debug it. You can remove those if you want to, since we now know that the Javascript actually successfully gets a response from the server. I've updated the answer with something you can try next.

Comment: Thanks @Frode. I think I am still going wrong somewhere. I have added my aspx code in my main question


My load is
    load: function(text) { document.getElementById("frm").innerHTML = text;  },

I still get NULL innerhtml. Please help

Comment: @user2837961 Okay. When you had the "Success!" dialog, did it say "Success! NULL"? Do you know how to use Firebug (or your browser's dev tools)? In the network tab, you should be able to see the request, and inspect the text returned from the server. Make sure you see the expected HTML generated by your ASPX page. Also, are you sure you changed "handleAs: 'json'" to "handleAs: 'text'"?

Comment: If I give "success" alert then I get a dialog with the message but with document.getElementById I get an error "Cannot set property innerHTML of null". I have even tried static mode and document.getElementById('<%=frm.ClientID%>') but its the same result. Yes I am using 'text' and not 'json'

Comment: @user2837961 Ok. Is there an element on your page with id equal to frm.ClientID ? Click view source on your page and make absolutely sure that the string given to getElementById is the same as the id of the container in which you want to place your form.

Comment: I do notice that your form actually has a `<body>` element. Remember that your page can only have a single body element, so the text you get with your Ajax call should not be placed verbatim on your page (you can worry about this problem later though :P).

Comment: Should the getElementById (div id) be a id on the current form where I want the form to be placed or is it the div id from the WebForm2? If its the "id on the current form", then is it not possible to open it as a popup? what id would I give in that case?

Comment: I just got it. All this time you meant id on the current page while I was setting it to the id in the WebForm2. It now works. Any idea as to how to make it a model dialog?

Comment: @user2837961 Nice! You can use dijit.Dialog if you want a modal dialog, and set its content in the load function. See updated answer.